# Add UNIQUE index fails with duplicate entry error, but no duplicates found

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, mariadb

Given table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  field_a CHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  field_b MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_c SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_d SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_e CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT '',
  field_f SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Required index:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_key (field_a, field_b);
```

Data size is about 51 Mio. rows. Following problem:

Attempt 1: If I try to create the index after the data is in the table it fails with duplicate key error. A select on the failed key returns only one(!) row.

```
 [23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-11111' for key 'idx_key'

 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE field_a='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' AND field_b='11111'
```

returns 1 (!)

Attempt 2: If I create the index on an empty table or make a combined private key and then put the data into the table, the table contains only 27 of 51 Mio. rows (!).

Is there some kind of a limit on the unique index or a bug?

I use MariaDB 10.0.20. Please help.

***Update 1***

A count of unique rows

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field_a,field_b) from mytable;
```

returns 50 Mio rows. So there are about 1 Mio duplicates. This however does not explain the 27 Mio from attempt 2 or wrong exception from attempt 1.

***Update 2***

the table used by the attempt 2:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  field_a CHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  field_b MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_c SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_d SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  field_e CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT '',
  field_f SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE KEY idx_key (field_a, field_b)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

***Update 3***

*Attempt 2 error solved*

To populate the table we use INSERT statements with multiple value rows in each. If a single value of the insert violated the unique constraint, all other values where also not inserted and caused 27 Mio rows instead of 50 Mio.

Approach 1:
However the bug with the wrong duplicate entry message still there even after the database were dropped and recreated, but this is an evil I can/must live with.

Comment: You can try searching for any duplicates using "select count(1) c from mytable group by field_a,field_b having c > 1;" - There might be some problem with collation or using CHAR instead of VARCHAR, but I was not able to find colliding test case (same version of mariadb)

Comment: I've already tried this this limit 100, but cancelled after 35 minutes. I however did an other count now. see my question update.

Comment: And please don't just describe attempt 2. Add in the question the exact code you used.

Comment: @kromit I see, can you try with limit 5 or 10 if it returns something faster? so you have some results at least, or adding index on (field_a,field_b) (non unique) might make it much faster too.

Comment: I suspect it might be a corrupted index or a collation issue. But why would anyone use MyISAM these days? InnoDB should be the preferred.

Comment: Can you try this query?: `select x.*, x2.* from (select t.* from mytable t where exists (select * from mytable d where d.field_a=t.field_a and d.field_b=t.field_b) limit 1) x left join mytable x2 where x2.field_a=x.field_a and x2.field_b=x.field_b ;`

Comment: @ypercube does not seem like corrupted index when they are actually just creating the index. I agree about InnoDB but it should not change the results.

Comment: @jkavalik right, they are trying to create the index. I meant corrupted table.

Comment: @kromit can you also tell us the OS you use and if you have replication?

Comment: using arch. no replication. I'll try your queries but this takes time :)

Comment: Is `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'` the actual value you use?

Comment: I once had a similar problem when the look was case sensitive (everything seemed unique) but the insertion of "Freq" failed because "FREQ" was already in the database. Maybe that's it?

Comment: All values I've used here are ony for example purpose. The char casing is also not the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the value`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-11111` in the message

```
[23000][1062] Duplicate entry 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-11111' for key 'mykey'
```

is the value that actually causes the violation. Seems to be a bug in MariaDB and in MySQL.

Comment: Could you make it into a test case with few to few thousands of rows which reproduces this?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this with 500k but without success. Seems to be something in >1 Mio area.

Comment: How did you conclude that there is no guarantee?

Comment: Because the returned combination exist only once. I guess its just a message bug. Evtl. the left or right neighbor is the real duplicate entry.

Comment: I agree with kromit. I have updated a table, setting UNIQUE to a field and the error message was wrong (indicating a value which was not duplicated). I was able to find the real "duplicate value" and they were not the one of the message.

Comment: How did you find real "duplicate value"  . I am also running in this issue, can please help me out to debug issue further

Answer (score 2):

**Plan A:**  Use `INSERT IGNORE` in your batched inserts.  That way the dup keys do not cause trouble.

**Plan B:**  Insert into a table with `INDEX`, not `UNIQUE`.  Then you can investigate the duplicates before deciding what to do with them.

You understand that `CHAR(15) utf8` occupies 45 bytes <strike>*always*</strike> *for most `ROW_FORMATs`*?  Perhaps `VARCHAR(15)` would be better?  (Please don't quote the debunked wives' tale about `FIXED` being better in MyISAM.)

Or maybe the data is, say, old IPv4 strings?  They work fine with `CHARACTER SET ascii` -- 15 bytes for `CHAR(15)` or 1-16 bytes for `VARCHAR(15)`.  Then, what about IPv6?  And about inability to compare ranges?